# NO_PUBKEY error when attempting to re-install Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: apt, gnupg

I try to execute the command `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get --reinstall software-center` but the below response is follow:

```
W: GPG error: http://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: 
   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key
   is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
E: Command line option --reinstall is not understood
```

First: I remove "View File" from Software Ubuntu Center after which my Software Ubuntu Center deleted as well.

How can I reinstall my Software Ubuntu Center?

Comment: `E: Command line option --reinstall is not understood`: try `install --reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest an alternative. Its call appgrid

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appgrid/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install appgrid
```

You can check `synaptic` package manager out as well..